# Rails: Form with custom button for update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have an app for booking shifts. When you book you should be able to add a short comment (string) and then press the book button.

I have the available shifts in a table, and want to have a text field like in a form, and add the (optional) text to the shift when you press the book-button.

This is what I have so far, when you book a shift, it shows correctly as booked, but the comment doesn't is not added (is nil).

Is there a smarter way to add a comment to a shift from the index view? Or how can I modify my code to work?

Index:

```
<% if shift.booked? && ( @booker == current_member || current_member.admin?) %>
  <td><%= link_to 'Avboka', un_book_shift_path(shift), method: :patch %></td>
<% elsif shift.booked? && @booker != current_member %>
  <td></td>
<% elsif shift.booked? %>
  <td><%= shift.comment %></td>
<% elsif (!shift.booked? && prev_lshift.booked? ) || index == 0 %>
  <td><%= form_for shift, :url => book_shift_path(shift) do |f| %>
          <%= f.label :comment, 'Kommentar' %>
          <%= f.text_field :comment %>
          <%= f.submit "Boka" %>
          </td>
          <% end %>
<% else %>
  <td></td>
<% end %>
```

shift controller:

```
def book
    @shift = Shift.find(params[:id])
    @shift.update_attributes(shift_params)
    member = Member.find(current_id)
    if SubShift.find_by(booked_by: current_id) == nil
      flash[:danger] = "danger"
      redirect_to shifts_url
    elsif @shift.overlaps?(@shift, current_id)
      flash[:danger] = "Danger"
      redirect_to shifts_url
    else
      @shift.book(current_id)
      redirect_to shifts_url
    end
end
```

shift model

```
def book(current_id)
    self.update(booked:true, booked_by:current_id)
end
```

Comment: what is your `shift_params`? (include it above as well) Are you not perhaps missing `:comment` as part of your whitelisted strong params?

Comment: You were right, I was missing the comment in the permitted params, thank you!